# Can I put a Core i7-3770 in a DQ67SW motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have an Intel DQ67SW motherboard with a Core i5-2500 CPU and I want to upgrade the CPU to Core i7-3770. I checked CPU support list on Intel's website it is not given there, but on Game Debate it is given as a compatible CPU.

If anyone has done this upgrade this please tell me. Also I'd be thankful for any advise you have about BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to upgrade it to core i7 3770. I checked cpu support list on intel's website it is not given there but on game debate it is given as a compatible CPU?

Your motherboard does not support 3rd Generation Core processors.

> For desktop boards based on the **Intel® Q67 Express Chipset**, Intel® Q65 Express Chipset, or Intel® B65 Express Chipset, upgrading from a 2nd Generation to a 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processor isn't possible.

Source: [Upgrading Desktop Boards to 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006050/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html?productId=51997&localeCode=us_en)

The Intel DQ67SW is a `Intel Q67 Express Chipset` motherboard.

Source: [Intel® Desktop Board DQ67SW](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/51997/intel-desktop-board-dq67sw.html)

Comment: Since your motherboard does not suppord 3rd Generation Intel Core processors.  I am not going to bother with the rest of your question, since the processor upgrade isn't even possible, it isn't even worth addressing those concerns.  If you want to upgrade to a 3rd Generation Intel Core processor you will have to purchase a compataible motherboard.

Comment: But according to a list given on 'Game Debate' 3770 series of core i7 CPUs are compatible with this board. I just want to ask if this information is true or not. Heres the source: https://www.game-debate.com/motherboard/index.php?mot_id=450&cpuList=Intel%20DQ67SW

Comment: Your source is likely incorrect.  I quoted the relevant information directly from the specification of the motherboard you have directly from Intel.

Answer (score 0):

yes go look at link.

https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel/DQ67SW.html

[https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel/DQ67SW.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2OaR.jpg)

Intel Desktop Board DQ67SW Executive Series -
Motherboard - Micro ATX - LGA1155
Socket - Q67 - USB 3.0, FireWire -
Gigabit Ethernet - onboard Graphics
(CPU Required) - HD Audio (8-Channel)

Brand   Intel
CPU Socket  LGA 1155
Compatible Devices  Personal Computer
RAM Memory Technology   DDR3
Chipset Type    Intel Q67 Express
Memory Clock Speed  1066 MHz
CPU Model   Core i5
Memory Storage Capacity 32 GB
RAM Memory Maximum Size 32 GB
Graphics Card Interface PCI, PCI Express

About this item
Processor Socket: LGA1155 Socket; Compatible Processors: Core i5, Core i3, Core i7
Memory: Max Supported Memory - 32 GB; Supported RAM Technology - DDR3 SDRAM;
Supported RAM Speed - 1333 MHz, 1066 MHz; Supported RAM Integrity Check - Non-ECC;
Supported RAM (Registered or Buffered) - Unbuffered; RAM Features -
Dual channel memory architecture
Audio: HD Audio (8-channel) Realtek ALC888S High Definition Audio
LAN: Network Controller - Intel 82579LM; Network Interfaces - Gigabit Ethernet
Storage Interfaces: Serial ATA-300 - connector(s): 2 x 7pin Serial ATA - 2 device(s) -
RAID 0 / RAID 1 / RAID 10 / RAID 5 ¦ Serial ATA-600 -
connector(s): 2 x 7pin Serial ATA - 2 device(s) -
RAID 0 / RAID 1 / RAID 10 / RAID 5
Note: Products with electrical plugs are designed for use in the US.
Outlets and voltage differ internationally and this product may require an
adapter or converter for use in your destination.
Please check compatibility before purchasing.

https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel/DQ67SW.html

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/51997/intel-desktop-board-dq67sw/specifications.html

Comment: Why did you link that 3 times? Also, when quoting, use proper formatting for that.